# About find domain name

Tags: php

I search in internet and i found this code for find domain name

```
function get_domain($url)
{
$pieces = parse_url($url);
$domain = isset($pieces['host']) ? $pieces['host'] : '';
if (preg_match('/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i', $domain, $regs)) 
{
return $regs['domain'];
}
return false;
}
```

Its works for http://www.google.com or http://www.google.co.uk

But its not working for test.web.tv.

Anybody can help me ?

How i can find min domain ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to get the URL ??

Comment: `parse_url()` sets variables in global space, so you should avoid that if possible (hacks). $_SERVER ... and ONE search on SO should do the job.

Comment: i want to get main domain for example test.hotmail.com ==> hotmail.com or test.hotmail.com.mx ==> hotmail.com.mx  or test.web.tv ==> web.tv or google.com ==> google.com

Comment: djot i didint uderstand your comment. Can u give me an example ?

Answer (score 1):

The function [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url) requires a valid URL. In this case `test.web.tv` isn't valid, so [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url) won't give you the expected results. In order to get around this, you could first check  if the URL has the `http://` prefix, and if it doesn't, manually prepend it. That way, you can get around the limitation of [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url).

However, I think it'd be better to use the following function.

```
function getDomain($url) 
{    
    if (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $url)) {
        $url = "http://" . $url;
    }

    $domain = implode('.', array_slice(explode('.', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST)), -2));
    return $domain;
}
```

Explanation:

- The given URL's passed to [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url) with the `PHP_URL_HOST` flag and the full host is obtained
- It's exploded with `.` as a delimiter
- The last two pieces of the array is sliced -- ie. the domain name
- It's joined back using [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode)

Test:

```
echo getDomain('test.web.tv');
```

Output:

```
web.tv
```

[**Demo!**](http://codepad.org/nMHmiK40)

Note: It's a modified version of my own answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18881399/1438393) combined with Alix's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762061/).

This function currently doesn't work for `.co.uk` domain extensions -- you can easily add a check and change the `array_slice` function accordingly.

Comment: Yes but this code is not working for test.hotmail.com.mx :(